# How to display a json get request where _something_ equals _anothersomething_ (Node.js, MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an **id** inside `req.params.id`.

```
var id = req.params.id // let's say this is 2
```

And let's say I have this from MongoDB:

```
[
    {
        "text": "hello",
        "fromId": "1"
    },
    {
        "text": "hi",
        "fromId": "1"
    },
    {
        "text": "hey",
        "fromId": "2"
    },
]
```

I use this to query through:

```
const message = await Message.find().select('text fromId');
const fromId = await Message.distinct('fromId');
```

And I want something like this (but of course this code is incorrent):

```
res.json(message).where(id === fromId);
```

So I want to get only this because my id is 2 and fromId is 2:

```
    {
        "text": "hey",
        "fromId": "2"
    },
```

I want the get request `res.json()` to display only the ones where **id is equal with fromId**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a filter object to `find` function to fetch only those documents where `fromId` is equal to `req.params.id`

```
const message = await Message.find({ fromId: req.params.id })
```

Comment: However be aware that `find()` always returns an array, even if only one document is found

Comment: @JeremyThille yes and as `fromId` is not unique across the collection, `find` is more suitable option as compared to `findOne`

Comment: Exactly, it depends on the use case

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're simply looking for

```
const message = await Message.findOne({"fromId": "2"})
```

You should also add `.lean()` so it returns simple JSON and is faster, and also `.exec()` to be non-blocking.

Full code :

```
const message = await Message.findOne({fromId: req.params.id}).lean().exec();

res.json(message);
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I helped

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using Mongoose? If it's a personal preference to not use ORMs, I understand but if you do change your mind. It's as simple as

```
const message = await Message.findById(id);  // This only takes mongoDB ids as arguments
// Use this for another general field
const message = await Message.findOne({fromId : id})
res.json(message).status(200);
```

You could also wrap it inside a try catch block to handle any errors if the document with the id wasn't found.

Comment: `Why are you not using Mongoose?` Well they are... It's a Mongoose model, and Mongoose is in the question's tags... And you just pretty much repeated my answer

Comment: @JeremyThille pardon me I didn't mean for it to come off as rude. I just didn't realize because the OP used a 'select' query which is very un-ORM like. As for repeating your answer, I was still typing out mine when yours got submitted. Apologies!

Comment: No worries. Mongoose also has a `.select()` method to select only the given fields